# How to sort/ group a Pandas data frame by class label or any specific column

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
class col2 col3 col4 col5
1     4    5    5    5
4     4    4.5  5.5  6
1     3.5  5    6    4.5
3     3    4    4    4
2     3    3.5  3.8  6.1
```

I have used hypothetical data in the example. The shape of the real DataFrame is 6680x1900. I have clustered these data into `50` labeled classes (1 to 50). How can I sort this data in ascending order of `class` labels?

I have tried:

```
df.groupby([column_name_lst])["class"]
```

But it fails with this error:

> TypeError: You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level'

How to solve this problem? Expected output is:

```
class col2 col3 col4 col5
1     4    5    5    5
1     3.5  5    6    4.5
2     3    3.5  3.8  6.1
3     3    4    4    4
4     4    4.5  5.5  6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) if `class` is `Series`:

```
print (type(df['class']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>


print (df.sort_values(by='class'))
   class  col2  col3  col4  col5
0      1   4.0   5.0   5.0   5.0
2      1   3.5   5.0   6.0   4.5
4      2   3.0   3.5   3.8   6.1
3      3   3.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
1      4   4.0   4.5   5.5   6.0
```

Also if need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), use parameter `by`:

```
print (df.groupby(by='class').sum())
       col2  col3  col4  col5
class                        
1       7.5  10.0  11.0   9.5
2       3.0   3.5   3.8   6.1
3       3.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
4       4.0   4.5   5.5   6.0
```

---

And if `class` is `index`, use [`Kartik solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653884/2901002):

```
print (df.index)
Int64Index([1, 4, 1, 3, 2], dtype='int64', name='class')

print (df.sort_index())
       col2  col3  col4  col5
class                        
1       4.0   5.0   5.0   5.0
1       3.5   5.0   6.0   4.5
2       3.0   3.5   3.8   6.1
3       3.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
4       4.0   4.5   5.5   6.0
```

Also if need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), use parameter `level`:

```
print (df.groupby(level='class').sum())
       col2  col3  col4  col5
class                        
1       7.5  10.0  11.0   9.5
2       3.0   3.5   3.8   6.1
3       3.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
4       4.0   4.5   5.5   6.0
```

or `index`, but first solution is better, because is more general:

```
print (df.groupby(df.index).sum())
       col2  col3  col4  col5
class                        
1       7.5  10.0  11.0   9.5
2       3.0   3.5   3.8   6.1
3       3.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
4       4.0   4.5   5.5   6.0
```

Comment: df.sort_values(by='class') this work perfectly. thanks

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with the data in your question:

> ```
> class col2 col3 col4 col5
> 1     4    5    5    5
> 4     4    4.5  5.5  6
> 1     3.5  5    6    4.5
> 3     3    4    4     4
> 2     3   3.5   3.8   6.1
> ```

And want to sort that, then it depends on whether `'class'` is an index or column. If index:

```
df.sort_index()
```

should give you the answer. If column, follow [answer by @jezarael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653849/3765319)